# d3 mouseover event doesnot work for all rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I have a simple bar chart with mouseover event. Before data update works code outside function *changeData* only. But after data has changed, works code inside function only. 
How can I write function to handle mouseover/out for all rectangels?

With button *OpacityNow* I can change opacity to all rects regardless if data has changed or not.

Thanks for help.

```
  var myCanvas1 = d3.select("#chart1")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", svgWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", svgHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .style("background", "aliceblue")
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
   .append("g");

   //append rectangles to svg container
  var Bar = myCanvas1.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray1)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance)); } )
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(+d.balance); })
    //.on("mouseover", function() {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.5)})
    //.on("mouseout", function() {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1)});

  //function for button click event
   function changeData(myDataArray) {

    var Bars = myCanvas1.selectAll("rect");
    var NewBars = Bars.data(eval(myDataArray));
    //enter new data
    NewBars.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        //.on("mouseover", function() {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.5)})
        //.on("mouseout", function() {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1)})
        .transition()
        .duration(duration1)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance)); } )
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(+d.balance); });
    //exit data
    NewBars.exit()
        .remove();
    //update data
    NewBars.transition()
        .duration(duration1)
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance)); } )
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(+d.balance); });

    //mouseover and mouseout event functions
    d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.3)});
    d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").selectAll("rect").on("mouseout", function(d) { d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1)});
   };

    //mouseover and mouseout event functions
  d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("fill", "red")});
  d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").selectAll("rect").on("mouseout", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("fill", "green")});

    //function click button to change opacity in all rects
   function OpacityNow() {
      d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").selectAll("rect").style("opacity", 0.3);
   };
   //function click button to change color in all rects
   function ColorNow() {
       d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").selectAll("rect").style("fill", "green");
   };
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write the code so that you don't repeat yourself or is the code you've provided not working in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. Unlike the button code, which runs *after*  you click the button, the mouseover code binds the event handlers to the `<rect>` elements present in the SVG *at that moment*.

Here is some code to demonstrate it.

Suppose we have this pattern:

```
//code for creating the bars
.on("mouseover", function(){ ... }//mouseover block, outside 'update'

update();

function update(){
    //code for updating the bars
}
```

In that case, the mouseover will handle the bars created *before* the update function runs.

Here is a demo to show you this. You can see that the mouseover at first works for all rects, but then, when new rectangles are created, it doesn't work anymore:

```js
var width = 400, height = 400;

var margin = {top:0, right:0, bottom:0, left:30};

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
 
var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
 .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
 .paddingInner(0.2);
 
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
 .tickSizeOuter(0);
 
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
 
var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
 .domain([0, 10]);
 
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
 .call(yAxis);
 
draw();
 
function draw(){

var data = getData();
 
xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value})]);
yScale.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.title}));

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
 .data(data, function(d){ return d.title});
 
bars.exit()
 .transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .attr("width", 0)
 .remove();
 
bars.enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("class", "bars")
 .attr("x", xScale(0) + 1)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", 0)
 .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(letters.indexOf(d.title)+1)})
 .merge(bars).transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .delay(1000)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", function(d){ return xScale(d.value)});

 d3.transition(svg).select(".y.axis")
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .delay(750)
   .call(yAxis);
}

function getData(){
 var title = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
 var data = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*title.length);
  data.push({title: title[index],
  value: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)});
  title.splice(index,1);
 }
 data = data.sort(function(a,b){ return d3.ascending(a.title,b.title)});
 return data;
};

setInterval(draw, 3000);

d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", function(){
    d3.select(this).attr("opacity", .5)
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, let's do another pattern:

```
//code for creating the bars

update();

function update(){
    //code for updating the bars
    .on("mouseover", function(){ ... }//mouseover block, inside 'update'
}
```

In this case, the mouseover only works *after* the function `update` has been called. Here is another demo, where the function will be called after 5 secs:

```js
var width = 400, height = 400;

var margin = {top:0, right:0, bottom:0, left:30};

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
 
var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
 .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
 .paddingInner(0.2);
 
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
 .tickSizeOuter(0);
 
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
 
var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
 .domain([0, 10]);
 
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
 .call(yAxis);
 
var data = getData();
 
xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value})]);
yScale.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.title}));

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
 .data(data, function(d){ return d.title});
 
bars.exit()
 .transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .attr("width", 0)
 .remove();
 
bars.enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("class", "bars")
 .attr("x", xScale(0) + 1)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", 0)
 .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(letters.indexOf(d.title)+1)})
 .merge(bars).transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .delay(1000)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", function(d){ return xScale(d.value)});
 
  d3.transition(svg).select(".y.axis")
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .delay(750)
   .call(yAxis);
 
function draw(){

var data = getData();
 
xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value})]);
yScale.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.title}));

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
 .data(data, function(d){ return d.title});
 
bars.exit()
 .transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .attr("width", 0)
 .remove();
 
bars.enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("class", "bars")
 .attr("x", xScale(0) + 1)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", 0)
 .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(letters.indexOf(d.title)+1)})
 .merge(bars).transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .delay(1000)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", function(d){ return xScale(d.value)});
 
 d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", function(){
    d3.select(this).attr("opacity", .5)
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1)
});

 d3.transition(svg).select(".y.axis")
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .delay(750)
   .call(yAxis);
}

function getData(){
 var title = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
 var data = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*title.length);
  data.push({title: title[index],
  value: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)});
  title.splice(index,1);
 }
 data = data.sort(function(a,b){ return d3.ascending(a.title,b.title)});
 return data;
};

setInterval(draw, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Only after that time the mouseover will work.

As I said before, the button will work for all rectangles, created before or after the `update` function, because it selects the rectangles presents in the SVG *when the button is pressed*.

If you don't want to repeat code (in case your `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions get bigger), you can set the functions separately:

```
//code for creating the bars
.on("mouseover", mouseover)//calls 'mouseover'
.on("mouseout", mouseout)//calls 'mouseout'

function update(){
    //code for updating the bars
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)//calls 'mouseover'
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)//calls 'mouseout'
}

function mouseover(){ ... }
function mouseout(){ ... }
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var width = 400, height = 400;

var margin = {top:0, right:0, bottom:0, left:30};

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
 
var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
 .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
 .paddingInner(0.2);
 
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
 .tickSizeOuter(0);
 
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
 
var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
 .domain([0, 10]);
 
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
 .call(yAxis);
 
draw();
 
function draw(){

var data = getData();
 
xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value})]);
yScale.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.title}));

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
 .data(data, function(d){ return d.title});
 
bars.exit()
 .transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .attr("width", 0)
 .remove();
 
bars.enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("class", "bars")
 .attr("x", xScale(0) + 1)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", 0)
 .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(letters.indexOf(d.title)+1)})
 .merge(bars).transition()
 .duration(1000)
 .delay(1000)
 .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.title)})
 .attr("width", function(d){ return xScale(d.value)});
  
  d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", mouseover).on("mouseout", mouseout);

 d3.transition(svg).select(".y.axis")
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .delay(750)
   .call(yAxis);
}

function getData(){
 var title = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
 var data = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*title.length);
  data.push({title: title[index],
  value: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)});
  title.splice(index,1);
 }
 data = data.sort(function(a,b){ return d3.ascending(a.title,b.title)});
 return data;
};

setInterval(draw, 3000);

d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", mouseover).on("mouseout", mouseout);

function mouseover(){
  d3.select(this).attr("opacity", .5);
}

function mouseout(){
  d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it works!  I would give plus 10 for the xamples but cant.  Thanks!